# qt returns bad math

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

`mlAnswer =  ( ( ( degreesPLato->text().toInt() * 1000000 ) * 3800 ) / answer );`

is the code in quesition
`mlAnswer` out puts -8223, while my calculator puts out 228000

debug output

`12  *  1000000  *  3800  /  200000  =  -8223`

all data types are `ints` Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ever hear of integer overflow?

Comment: yes I tried with long long int and get the same result

Comment: Let me guess... by changing the variable mlAnswer? It's too late by then. The equation is never evaluated based on the data type it's going into. It's cast from whatever type it ends up with to that type only on assignment after the equation has already been evaluated. Try putting "LL" after 1000000.

Comment: Yes adding LL to the end of the 100000 fixed the problem. Thank you. Could you elaborate a little more on the cause of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12 * 1000000 * 3800 = 45.6 billion.

This is out of range for a 4 byte signed integer, which is what `int` usually is.  Try using `long long` instead.

The default type of an integer literal is `int`, unless the number is too big to fit in an `int`.  As long as you are doing math operations between ints, the results remain as ints.  `12` is an `int`, `1000000` is an `int`, and `3800` is an `int`.  When you multiply them together, the result is still an `int`, even though it no longer fits.  Add the `LL` suffix to make the integer literal a long long. i.e. `12LL`, `1000000LL`, `3800LL`, etc...

Comment: @Cjueden: We'll need to see a complete code example that demonstrates the problem then.

Comment: Yes, what darron just said, add `L`, i.e. `12L` should be enough.

Comment: @JesseGood: `12LL` for long long, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot `long` was still 32-bits on windows.

Comment: also you should check the input number to be in a valid range. maybe it will work with 3800, but at some point it will overflow again

Comment: In Qt it's convinient to use `qint64` for `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by reordering your operations:

```
12 * 1000000 * 3800 / 200000
```

Will overflow an `int`, however:

```
12 * 1000000 / 200000 * 3800
```

will not.

Note that this will only give the same answer if the numerator is an integer multiple of the denominator. Using `LL` is a better solution on platforms that support it, but if you are constrained to a 4 byte `int` type, this will at least stop overflow in more situations.